# How to manipulate edges of rectangle square draw on touch event in Iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, touch, uigesturerecognizer

I am drawing a square on touch using touchBegine & touchEnded points.Now my requirement is how modify particular edge of this square on touch?Is this possible to modify edges of rect with touch?

Comment: do you mean like resizing it after it has been drawn?

Comment: @Omar Yes I want re-size but I want re-size particular edge or boundary.